# show messages from logfile in realtime on desktop

Tags: pipe

I want to show messages from a logfile in realtime on desktop. (xfce4 on fedora 24)

My idea is to do this by using notify-send and tail -f in a shell script.

So far I have two shell scripts:

1. `read_data.sh`
2. `write_data.sh`

Both fork a process and communicates via a pipe.

`write_data.sh`:

```
tail -f /var/log/logfile > mypipe
```

`read_data.sh`:

```
mkfifo mypipe

while true
do
    echo "read now from pipe"
    if read line <mypipe; then
        echo $line
    fi
done
```

Unfortunately I get an error message:

```
EPIPE (Broken pipe)
```

I used strace to analyze what's going on:

`write_data.sh`:

```
strace tail -f /var/log/logfile > mypipe
....
write(1, "Message from logfile"..., 281) = -1 EPIPE (Broken pipe)
--- SIGPIPE {si_signo=SIGPIPE, si_code=SI_USER, si_pid=7314, si_uid=0} ---
+++ killed by SIGPIPE +++


strace read_data.sh
...
read(0, "\n", 1)                        = 1
dup2(10, 0)                             = 0
fcntl(10, F_GETFD)                      = 0x1 (flags FD_CLOEXEC)
close(10)                               = 0
open(".", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0550, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
getdents(3, /* 133 entries */, 32768)   = 5400
getdents(3, /* 0 entries */, 32768)     = 0
close(3)                                = 0
write(1, "message from logfile ....
) = 62
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [CHLD], [], 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
write(1, "read now from pipe\n", 19read now from pipe
)    = 19
open("/tmp/mypipe", O_RDONLY
```

`read_data.sh` blocks at this point.

Any idea why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

The SIGPIPE is caused by the fact that your reading loop opens and
closes the FIFO file for reading at every iteration. Try this instead:

```
while read line; do
    echo "$line"
done <"$pipe"
```